# Generalisation of Lyapunov time to stochastic dynamical systems

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, stochastic-differential-equations

Might there be useful generalisations of the Lyapunov time to stochastic dynamical systems? In particular, I'm interested in methods for calculating confidence intervals around stochastic analogues of the Lyapunov time.

**Motivation**: While I have used the Lyapunov time for problems in celestial mechanics, here I'm motivated by problems within the domain of bounded rationality. In particular, it could help us figure out whether, for a large class of dynamic environments, there's a time horizon beyond which it isn't reasonable for a biological agent to plan.

Comment: What sort of problems do you envision this analog will address?

Comment: I'm thinking about this problem within the context of bounded rationality and the relative importance of computation for inference. In particular, I think it can help us figure out whether there's a time horizon beyond which it isn't reasonable for a biological agent to plan.

Comment: sure, look here : http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540637585